# How to solve publish self-contained console app failure because of package downgrade?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

I was trying to publish a self-contained .net core app, I run the publish command :

**Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core>dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x64**

I get the following output indicating the the restore phase failed :

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Restoring packages for  Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj...
>   Restoring packages for  Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Entities\Vrops.Entities.csproj...                                                                                   Restoring packages for  Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Messaging\Vrops.Messaging.csproj...                                                                                 Restoring packages for  Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Logging\Vrops.Logging.csproj...                                                                                     Generating MSBuild file  Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Entities\obj\Vrops.Entities.csproj.nuget.g.props.                                                                  Restore completed in 299.56 ms for  Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Entities\Vrops.Entities.csproj.                                                                         Restore completed in 299.56 ms for  Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Logging\Vrops.Logging.csproj.                                                                           Restoring packages for  Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj...
>   Generating MSBuild file  Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Messaging\obj\Vrops.Messaging.csproj.nuget.g.props.                                                                Restore completed in 512.2 ms for  Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Messaging\Vrops.Messaging.csproj.                                                                        Generating MSBuild file  Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Core\obj\Vrops.Core.csproj.nuget.g.props.                                                                          Generating MSBuild file  Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Core\obj\Vrops.Core.csproj.nuget.g.targets.                                                                        Restore completed in 763.18 ms for  Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj.
>                                                                              Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605: Detected
>   package downgrade: System.Diagnostics.Debug from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11.
>   Reference the package dire ctly from the project to select a different
>   version.  [ Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]
>   Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 ->
>   Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 2.1.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem
>   4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> Sys tem.Diagnostics.Debug (>= 4.3.0)  [ Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]                                                                                  Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Debug
>   (>= 4.0.11) [ Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Co re.csproj]
>   Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605: Detected
>   package downgrade: System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives from 4.3.0 to
>   4.0.1. Reference the packag e directly from the project to select a different version.  [ Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]
>   Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 ->
>   Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 2.1.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem
>   4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> Sys tem.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.3.0)  [ Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]                                                                           Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 ->
>   Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 2.1.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem
>   4.0.1 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.0.1) [C :\Users\ZakariaI\Desktop\V2\Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]                                                                                                                      Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605: Detected
>   package downgrade: System.Runtime.Handles from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1.
>   Reference the package directl y from the project to select a different
>   version.  [ Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]
>   Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 ->
>   Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 2.1.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem
>   4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> Sys tem.Runtime.Handles (>= 4.3.0)  [ Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]                                                                                    Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 ->
>   Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 2.1.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem
>   4.0.1 -> System.Runtime.Handles (>= 4.0.1) [C:\Users\Z akariaI\Desktop\V2\Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]                                                                                                                               Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605: Detected
>   package downgrade: System.Runtime.InteropServices from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0.
>   Reference the package  directly from the project to select a different
>   version.  [ Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]
>   Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 ->
>   Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 2.1.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem
>   4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> Sys tem.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.3.0)  [ Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]                                                                            Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 ->
>   Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 2.1.0 ->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.1.0)
>   [C:\Users\ZakariaI\Desktop\V2\Vro ps 1.2.0\Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]                                                                                                                                                     Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605: Detected
>   package downgrade: System.Diagnostics.Debug from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11.
>   Reference the package dire ctly from the project to select a different
>   version.  [ Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]
>   Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 -> Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1 ->
>   System.Xml.ReaderWriter 4.0.11 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 ->
>   runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 
>   4.3.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Debug (>= 4.3.0)  [ Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]                                                                      Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Debug
>   (>= 4.0.11) [ Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Co re.csproj]
>   Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605: Detected
>   package downgrade: System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives from 4.3.0 to
>   4.0.1. Reference the packag e directly from the project to select a different version.  [ Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]
>   Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 -> Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1 ->
>   System.Xml.ReaderWriter 4.0.11 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 ->
>   runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 
>   4.3.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.3.0)  [ Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]                                                               Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 -> Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1 ->
>   System.Xml.ReaderWriter 4.0.11 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>=
>   4.0.1) [C:\Users\ZakariaI\D esktop\V2\Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]                                                                                                                                        Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605: Detected
>   package downgrade: System.Runtime.Handles from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1.
>   Reference the package directl y from the project to select a different
>   version.  [ Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]
>   Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 -> Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1 ->
>   System.Xml.ReaderWriter 4.0.11 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 ->
>   runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 
>   4.3.0 -> System.Runtime.Handles (>= 4.3.0)  [ Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]                                                                        Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 -> Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1 ->
>   System.Xml.ReaderWriter 4.0.11 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 ->
>   System.Runtime.Handles (>= 4.0.1)  [ Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]                                                                                                                   Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605: Detected
>   package downgrade: System.Runtime.InteropServices from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0.
>   Reference the package  directly from the project to select a different
>   version.  [ Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]
>   Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 -> Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1 ->
>   System.Xml.ReaderWriter 4.0.11 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 ->
>   runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 
>   4.3.0 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.3.0)  [ Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]                                                                Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj : error NU1605:  Vrops.Orm ->
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions 2.6.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
>   2.2.6 -> Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 2.2.6 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 -> Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1 ->
>   System.Xml.ReaderWriter 4.0.11 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>=
>   4.1.0) [C:\Users\ZakariaI\De sktop\V2\Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops 1.2.0\Vrops.Core\Vrops.Core.csproj]                                                                                                                                          Generating MSBuild file  Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\obj\Vrops.Orm.csproj.nuget.g.props.                                                                            Restore failed in 503.41 ms for  Vrops
>   1.2.0\Vrops.Orm\Vrops.Orm.csproj.

Comment: if you've already built the project, you could try using `--no-build`, or if you've already restored successfully, you could try `--no-restore`. Although I'd be curious why `dotnet restore` would succeed and `dotnet publish` would fail to restore.

Comment: Looks like you've got some version mismatches and it likely doesn't know which version of your dependencies to publish.  I recommend going through your output and selecting the correct versions of your dependencies and making sure all are on the same.